# Getting only last element from this map method every time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, mern

OnSubmit I am calling handleSubmit function which has two parameters event, doc.

```
const handleRename = (e, doc) => {
    console.log(doc); 
}
```

now inside render section I have array and model form for each of that element like below:

```
{
   ArrayName.map((doc) => {
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleRename(e, doc)}>
        ...
      </form>
}
```

instead of getting individual doc, I am getting last element of Array each time.
Can anyone know what's going wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
ArrayName.map((doc) => {
  return (<form onSubmit={(e) => {handleRename(e, doc)}}>
    ...
  </form>)
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that page will explain best the error. Check the advanced syntax

(e) => handleRename(e, doc) this section of your code, instead of returning a function it evaluates it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct track but you just missed returning the component from the array mapping.

```
ArrayName.map((doc) => {
   return (
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleRename(e, doc)}>
         ...
      </form>
   );
}
```

or better just shorthand the return statement:

```js
ArrayName.map((doc) => (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleRename(e, doc)}>
       ...
    </form>
));
```

More info on [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Shorthand [React return on map](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/13/rendering-an-array-of-data-with-map-and-jsx)